# How to configure cmake to compile informix *.ec files?

Tags: cmake, informix, embedded-sql

I'm just found cmake and I want to use it to create make files for a little project that uses the esql compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used `cmake` yet (it is on my list of things that I need to look at - round about the time some spare tuits become available), but...

I do have several sets of rules for compiling ESQL/C to object code etc for regular `make`.

You can find one set of those rules online at the [IIUG Software Archive](http://www.iiug.org/software/) in the SQLCMD package.  Or you can contact me directly to discuss the niceties in detail (and/or the differences between `cmake` stuff and regular `make` stuff).  You can also find Informix-related `autoconf` macros in the SQLCMD package - file `acinformix.m4`.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? I understand that it addressed the OP's _need_ but it did not answer the _question_. Now I'm here nearly eight years on looking for an answer to the same question and this is not the answer. I have make rules already. I am trying to leave make for cmake.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use the cmake [ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2.6.html#command:add_custom_command) command to create the rule for compiling each source file with the esql compiler.